# WP Page Builder - Remove table border?

Tags: css

I guess I should ask in the Page Builder support forum... but I guess this applies to a 'general WP' discussion...

I am using an [Oshine] Child theme, I added this code to the child/css file.... no good so far. Tried both '0' and 'none'

table,
td {
    border: none;
}

Any idea how may I remove the border?
here's my website: [zemaraim.com](http://zemaraim.com/) in case it helps.... the table is right underneath the main splash/slider.... above the thumbnails ...

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `table, table td{ border:none!important; }`?

Comment: Just did. Nothing :(